# [AS3]How can I casting AObject to BObject automatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, casting, type-conversion

I want to cast AObject to BObject automatically like toString().
My original code is below:

```
var a:AObject = new AObject();
var b:BObject = new BObject();
```

someFunction(b:BObject):void{}

```
someFunction(a.toBObject());  // no error
trace(a.toString());          //[object AObject]
```

So, I want to finish it like toString()

```
someFunction(a);   //TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed
trace(a);          //[object AObject]
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: There's no such thing. You have to cast it manually, like `a as BObject` or `BObject(a)`.

Comment: What are those two classes? Why and how are they different? It's not a good idea to learn from arbitrary made up pseudo code. Explain your goal, not just the solution that you came up with. What is that function doing?

Comment: There's no such thing as automatic casting in any language. Type have to be compatible to start with. If used as parameters, the parameter type has to be of the highest superclass encapsulating the objects or of the shared interface type.

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to pass two arbitrary objects that might be handled similarly, you can use interfaces to "hide" the differences and expose the seemingly shared functionality.  I'm not saying this is good practice for your situation, but it is a solution.  As in...

```
public interface CommonGround
{
    function toString() : String;
}

public class AObject implements CommonGround
{
    public function toString() : String
    {
        // implement here
    }
}

public class BObject implements CommonGround
{
    public function toString() : String
    {
        // implement here
    }
}
```

...and then use them elsewhere in the program...

```
public someFunction( obj:CommonGround ) : void
{
    trace( obj.toString() );
}
```

...or...

```
var obj:CommonGround = new AObject();
trace( obj.toString() );
```